# Selecting multiple same value rows out of the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table, where one of the columns is named `mid`. It has a lot of values, some of them repeat themselves. Theres also a column named `chashrate`. It has a different value for each mid row. Theres also a column named `pid`, which shows the id of each row.

I've tried pulling out specific value rows with `HAVING`, but I can only do one value at a time or multiple values that dont match each other

```
$miner = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE pid='6'")->fetchall();
```

What I need to do is collect all the same `MID` column value rows, with the id `pid=6` so for example all of the `mid = 8`; `pid=6`, collect their `chashrate` and sum it up. So for example I would get `mid(8)=17394`, `mid(6)=28424` etc.

Here's a photo of the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRs9X.png

The same colored rows need to be selected and their chashrate values summed up.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUM` to sum the cashrate values and `GROUP BY` to group them by mid.

```
SELECT mid
     , SUM(`cashrate`) AS total
FROM `data`
WHERE pid = 6
GROUP BY mid;
```

Check it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eLBg2tPpK8taWXr4ik3Khp/0).

For the given data on the image, this query will output the following result:

```
mid | total
6   | 981
8   | 374
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select mid, sum(chashrate) as sum_chashrate
from data
where pid = 6
group by pid, mid;
```

This will return multiple rows, one for each `mid` value.

You can do this for multiple `pid`s -- or even all of them, by removing or changing the `where` clause.